# Not able to connect with Sybase database

Tags: java, database, jdbc, sybase

In java I am trying to connect with Sybase database through java program as shown below

```
public static void connect() {

        SybDriver sybDriver = null;
        Connection conn;

        try {
            sybDriver = (SybDriver) Class.forName(
                //  "com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver").newInstance();
                    "com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver").newInstance();
            System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            boolean isTrue = conn.isValid(3);
            System.out.println(isTrue);
```

But i am getting the below exception

Driver Loaded

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.isValid(I)Z
    at connectionTry.connect(connectionTry.java:97)
    at connectionTry.main(connectionTry.java:23)
```

I have done analysis in google what i have to came up to know jconnn.jar is missing as the issue is the method isValid(I)Z is not there in jconn2.jar is not there please advise how to overcome from this error please.

Comment: To which database version you want to connect. Maybe you need a different JDBC driver version. Have a look for here [include SQL anywhere version 9.0.2 - 16.0](http://scn.sap.com/community/sql-anywhere/blog/2014/05/02/connecting-to-sql-anywhere-using-jdbc)

Answer (score 2):

The driver you are using is - based on the class name in the stacktrace - a JDBC 2 driver. The `isValid` method was added in Java 6 (or: JDBC 4), so you can't use it with a driver that doesn't implement it.

You either need to upgrade to a newer driver: contact Sybase for that, or simply not call the `isValid` method. In the code you show there is no reason to call it: you just created the connection, of course it is valid. This method is intended to check the validity of long-living connections (eg in the context of a connection pool).

Answer (score 0):

AbstractMethodError is thrown when the implementation class doesn't comply to the signature defined in the abstract class. Use a compatible version of the implementation or alternatively avoid the methods that conflict.

Ideally latest version of drivers must be having matching implementations or you will have to contact sybase to fix that.